# Java Spring common way to implement user authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to Java and I trying to write first web application with Spring framework (I have some experience with django/python and sinatra/ruby).
I need to implement user authentication system and have no idea what is the best way to do this correctly. Should I use Spring Security for this? Or there is some another ways?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you starting a new application, I strongly urge to use [Spring Boot](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/). It will take away a lot of your initial pain in configuring the various aspects of Spring.

As for security, you should go with Spring Security which of course is easy to configure with Spring Boot.

Following [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/) guide, a simple Spring Security configuration which uses in memory authentication would look like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        http
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

As you can see, the first method is used to configure which parts of the application are to be secured and how, while the second method configures how the users will be authenticated.

One common way to provide a customized way to authenticate users, is to provide a custom `UserDetailsService` implementation as is done [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/03/springmvc4-spring-data-jpa-springsecurity-configuration-using-javaconfig.html)

A very easy way to configure authentication when you already have configured a `DataSource` and the user credentials are stored there, is the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;



    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        http
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
}

    @Override
    protected void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER").and()
                .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN").and()
                .withDefaultSchema();
    }
```

}

[Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/) is the complete reference of Spring Security. Also [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security) is security part of the Spring Boot documentation. You can find a multitude of sample applications using various aspects of Spring Security [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-javaconfig/tree/master/samples/)

Initially it may seem that Spring Security is complicated, but once you get the hang of it, you'll appreciate it's extended feature set and customizability.

One final note, when to comes to things like security which are common in so many applications, there is no need to reinvent the wheel! Go with Spring Security (or perhaps [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/))

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response! :)